# Permanent damage on soft bodies

Tags: animation, collision, soft-body

I trie to make my cube crush into a softbody object so he left some visible damage on it.

[image]

But when i use "plasticity" the damage outcome is based on the vertices that bounces back outsite like shown on the picture, thats pretty much the result i get.

I also tried to use vertex groups, i heard making the impact area unaffected by "goal" is a solution but then this vertex group just sacks in and when i tried to make it more stable like using "bending" it will completly ignores any impact and just bounce off.

Any way to make some kind of visible damage when the cube moved through the head?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think soft body physics are all that suitable for what you're seeking.  You have to animate it.

[image]

It would take a full tutorial to cover the process, but it can broken down into basic steps which are briefly explained.  The Blend file has been included below.

It's an older version -  Use CTL left & right arrows to switch between windows.  ALT-A plays the animation.

.

The first step is to point out that the Monkey not be given physics of any kind.  Instead place an icosphere (or similar), a passive Rigid body, inside the head and lower down so the cube will penetrate the Monkey's scalp and bounce off the icosphere.

[image]

Because physics will vary it's behavior at the slightest change, the cube's fall and bounce to the ground is baked.  Hence the cube has no physics.

With the Monkey also free and unconstrained, it can be animated to react to the impact.  It is scaled smaller in the Z axis when the cube hits, then recovers after.
NOTE - the Monkey's Origin Point is set to it's lowest vertice.

Note also how the sphere is animated to rise after the impact to keep the cube clear of the monkey's surfaces on exit.  It looks like it's sliding off, not bouncing off which I would see as normal for a soft body collision.  (The icosphere would normally be invisible)

[image]

Next step is to emulate damage.  To that end a part of the scalp is subdivided generously so we see a more curved depression when that area is pulled down inside by the empty inside the head, a "Graduated hook".  See the Hook "Radius" setting in the Hook Modifier.

[image]

[image]

That covers the basics.  If the Monkey is to fall over, then extra work is required. If you get stuck, ask a new question outlining the problem.

[image]